# how to filter properties with values in Neptune + nodejs

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

with Neptune + nodejs

`g.V().hasLabel('A').properties()`

returns:

```
id, label, value
1, 'p1','v1'
2, 'p1','b2'
3, 'p1','b3'
4, 'p1','d4'
```

how can I do a filter so it only returns:

```
id, label, value
2, 'p1','b2'
3, 'p1','b3'
```

I tried

`g.V().hasLabel('Device').properties().value().is(containing('b'))`

but it throws error UnsupportedOperationException

I also tried
`g.V().hasLabel('Device').where(properties().value().is(containing('b')))`

same error, but i think it is because i have different data type in multiple properties, the containing method failed when it come across number type.....

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not need to use `properties` unless you are planning to do something like drop the property. You should be able to simply do:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Device').has('value',containing('b'))
```

I am assuming that "value" is the name of your property. If it is not please clarify.

EDITED to add more examples.

If you wanted to test all properties you could do something like this which wil find the matching properties.

```
gremlin> g.addV('test').property('x','Hello').
                        property('y','Another one').
           addV('test').property('y','Goodbye')

==>v[12b93051-decf-3be5-85cd-cbc4c27e42f9]

g.V().hasLabel('test').
      properties().hasValue(TextP.containing('ll'))

==>vp[x->Hello]
```

If you want the vertex that contains the properties

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('test').
             where(properties().hasValue(TextP.containing('ll')))

==>v[14b93051-dece-db72-9f46-46df7513a14c]
```

Comment: I actually have a requirement to query all the properties, any properties contains 'xyz', is there a way to replace your example 'value' to be all properties?

Comment: I added more examples that show how to retrieve either the matching properties or the vertices that contain those properties.

Comment: the query fails if the properties contain different type of data, e.g. number, I think this is a known issue

Comment: Yes. There is an issue open on the ApacheTinkerpop Jira for that when using the TextP predicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *filter* :

```
g.V().hasLabel('Device').filter({ it.getProperty("value").startsWith("b") })
```

or

```
g.V().hasLabel('Device').filter({ it.getProperty("value").contains("b") })
```

EDIT:
This query works in pure Gremlin not Neptune version.

Comment: It is desirable to avoid using closures in general and stick to pure Gremlin steps. As the OP is using Amazon Neptune this is especially so as Groovy closures in queries are not supported.